# Reason why a shell command behave differently depending on OS

Tags: shell, command-line, operating-system, posix, portability

Like `sed`, there are shell commands which don't behave in the same way in the same shell.

Behavior of them seems to be different depending on OS (*BSD or GNU/Linux) not on shell though they are **shell** commands. I wonder at this. Could anyone please explain why shell scripting doesn't behave the same way on multiple platforms?

Comment: BSD and GNU have similar binaries, but not identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different systems evolved their own tools and syntax, to a certain degree. Linux uses the GNU toolchain, which supports a variety of modern options. However, there is one thing that Linux and BSD (and many other Operating Systems) have in common: [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

This is the [POSIX specification for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). You can rely on these working on all *nix platforms. There is usually a way to do whatever you're trying to do in a way that works with all versions of `sed`.

You'll also find the same inconsistencies between `awk` and `gawk`.

Comment: Thank you for an answer(I didn't know POSIX.). So, Is this difference, metaphorically, a kinda like a difference between Microsoft Word in Mac and that in Windows ?

Comment: Pretty much, except Microsoft makes both of those, and different development teams create these respective versions of `sed` and `awk`. The only thing that really ties them together is POSIX. You'll probably find that the *BSD options for `sed` and `awk` are more likely to work with GNU/Linux than the GNU/Linux ones are to work with BSD.

Comment: thanks ! very understandable. From now on I may be able to examine father by myself thanks to your comment.